# Associate URL to keywords separated

Tags: php, url, keyword

I have a variable `$keywords`

The content of this variable are words separated by commas or spaces 
for example:

```
$keywords= key1,key2,key3
```

Or

```
$keywords=key1 key2 key3
```

the table that I have is:

```
        <table width="500" border="1">
  <tr>
    <td height='auto'>Keywords: $keywords</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I want explode `$keywords` in key1 key2 key3 ...
And associate to each separated word a predifined URL:

```
http://miosite.com/search/label/key1
http://miosite.com/search/label/key2
http://miosite.com/search/label/key3
```

So I want get this:

```
       <table width="500" border="1">
  <tr>
    <td height='auto'>Keywords: key1,key2,key3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Where

```
        key1=http://miosite.com/search/label/key1
        key2=http://miosite.com/search/label/key2
        key1=http://miosite.com/search/label/key3
```

How to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check for the comma to determine which delimiter to explode on, then put together the string again:

```
if (strpos($keywords,",") !== FALSE) {
  $keys = explode(",",$keywords);
} else {
  $keys = explode(" ",$keywords);
}
$keywords = "";
foreach ($keys as $key) $keywords .= "http://miosite.com/search/" . $key . "<BR>";
```

EDIT: Apparently the object is to REMOVE the site address, not add it... no one figured that out.  new code:

```
if (strpos($keywords,",") !== FALSE) {
  $keys = explode(",",$keywords);
} else {
  $keys = explode(" ",$keywords);
}
$keywords = "";
foreach ($keys as $key) $keywords .= str_ireplace("http://miosite.com/search/","",$key) . ",";
$keywords = substr($keywords,0,strlen($keywords)-1);
```

Hackish, but give that a shot.

Edit: Oh now they need to be linked? LOL

```
if (strpos($keywords,",") !== FALSE) {
  $keys = explode(",",$keywords);
} else {
  $keys = explode(" ",$keywords);
}
$keywords = "";
foreach ($keys as $key) {
   $newkey = str_ireplace("http://miosite.com/search/","",$key);
   $keywords .= "<a href=\"" . $key . "\">" . $newkey . "</a>,";
}
$keywords = substr($keywords,0,strlen($keywords)-1);
```

Ok, try that out.

Comment: ok i have tried your code but how output i get:  Keywords: http://miosite/search/label/keyword1,
http://miosite/search/label/keyword2,
http://miosite/search/label/keyword3 instead of keyword1,keyword2.keyword3 and link are not linkable or active

Comment: @grigione added another piece of code... we all assumed you were adding the url based on the question.

Comment: the second code give me Keywords: keyword1,keyword2,keyword3 ma they not are active or linkable

Comment: @grigione let's try the third one.

Comment: ok code working .. now i get keyword1.keyword2.keyword3 but keyword1  link is http://miosite.com/keyword1 instead of http://miosite.com/search/keyword1 ps i want: http://miosite.com/search/label/keyword1

Answer (score 0):

```
$keywords = explode(',',$keywords);
foreach($keywords as $key) echo("<a href=\"http://miosite.com/search/{$key}\">{$key}</a>");
```

Answer (score 0):

Keywords:

```
$keywords = explode(',',$keywords);
$tmpArray = array();
foreach($keywords as $key) {
    $tmpArray[] = 'http://miosite.com/search/label/'.$key;
}

echo implode(",", $tmpArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

Iam just rewrting by embeddg php within html & taken are of caommas between your links:

```
 <?php
$keywords = 'key1 key2 key3';
$keywords = preg_split('/[, ]/',$keywords);

foreach($keywords as $key)
    $links[]= "<a href=http://miosite.com/search/{$key}\>{$key}</a>";
    print_r($links);

$keywords  = implode(',',$links);   

?>

<table width="500" border="1">
  <tr>
    <td height='auto'>Keywords: <?php  echo $keywords ;?>
</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```